# HTTP Header's not matching

Tags: nginx, php, curl

Is there a difference between what headers php returns and what is set in nginx?

When I run:

```
curl -I mydomain.com
```

I get as expected (I have `keep-alive off`)

```
Connection: close
```

But when I output the `$_SERVER[HTTP_CONNECTION]` on that same domain I get:

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

I am not sure why php is returning keep-alive where everywhere else I pull the headers and it shows connection closed.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER[HTTP_CONNECTION]` in PHP contains `Connection` header from client's request, telling the server that client supports keep-alive.

What you see with cURL's output, is the response from server, telling that connection will be closed instead of kept open for keep-alive.

Comment: I thought I read that somewhere but the problem is I go to another site hosted that is hosted via GoDaddy and in the same browser and it shows Connection: close as the PHP variable.